# How to use <script> inside Gatsby React page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gatsby, script-tag

I have a script with jQuery and I want to use it inside my gatsby react page.
So first I Created a file in my project nestpay.js and I paste the script content inside it like that:

```
    function submitformpaiement()
{
// code here
}
```

Second I added const payScript = require('../pages/nestpay') inside render()

```
render() {
const payScript = require('../pages/nestpay')
return (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet title="donation" />
    <Nav />
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```

}

and when I run the project I got tons of syntax errors in my nestpay.js file.

> ./src/pages/nestpay.js Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> C:\Users\PREDATOR\Desktop\gatsby\ticketsadaka\src\pages\nestpay.js
>   205:19  warning  Unexpected mix of '>>>' and '|'
>   no-mixed-operators   205:25  warning  Unexpected mix of '>>>' and '|' 
>   no-mixed-operators   216:3   error    'strlen' is not defined
>   no-undef   219:7   error    'strlen' is not defined
>   no-undef   219:37  error    'strlen' is not defined
>   no-undef   220:10  error    'strlen' is not defined
>   no-undef   220:45  error    'strlen' is not defined
>   no-undef   222:12  warning  'i' is already defined
>   no-redeclare   232:14  warning  'j' is already defined
>   no-redeclare   262:12  warning  'i' is already defined
>   no-redeclare

This a picture of my file.
[image]

I think I miss something in that file a header or an import I don't know what.

I test that script in an HTML page and it's work fine so I need your help how to use it inside gatsby react page.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: First, should add your errors so people can give more accurate answers. Second, take your 'require' statement to the top of the file (before the declaration) and add semicolons to your lines (just some format), mainly the return statement just after the parenthesis and before the closing brackets.

Comment: @JoséCordero I added my errors

Comment: @JoséCordero what return statement you talk about??

Comment: The 'return' i'm talking about is the one inside your 'render()' method. What happens if you delete the import line ('const payScript = require...')? It looks like your errors are coming from there due to a var or function not being declared.

Comment: @JoséCordero the return inside render() is the gatsby format when u create a new file I didn't change any thing and I took the 'require' statement to the top of the file and still got the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to include a  tag is to just inline it in your main index.html like `<script src="../pages/nestpay.js"</script>` in the  or  tags.

P.S: Why do you want to include a jQuery file  when using React GatsbyJS though?

Comment: I don't have any files .html I have index.js so I can't do what you offer.

Comment: PS: I use that script jquery coz is the module integration kit for online payment so they have just that version.

Comment: I think this [page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) should help you out. They have code examples for how you might want to include scripts. I have used the last `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop with the `{}.__html` syntax and it did the trick for me. You should also check out React Helmet, which might fit your use case.